# Drawn shape on SurfaceView is not getting translucent

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I used *GL10 SurfaceView* and drawn squares on it. But i want squares to be translucent to view the background. I used 
 // set color

`gl.glColor4f(color[0], color[1], color[2], color[3]/*alpha*/);` 
but decreasing alpha results the square darker, not translucent.
I've also applied Blending options

```
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    gl.glAlphaFunc(GL10.GL_GREATER, 0);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
```

but nothing works.

> EDIT / ADDED

#### used GL configuration for translucent

```
  this.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
  // this.getHolder().setFormat( PixelFormat.RGBA_8888 );
  this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
  mRenderer = new MyGLRenderer();
  mRenderer.context = context;
  setRenderer(mRenderer);
  setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
```

#### for plane Construct

```
float squareCoords[] = { x, 0f, lenght, // top left
                    x, 0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
                    x - 6, 0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
                    x - 6, 0f, lenght }; // top right

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                squareCoords.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
                drawOrder.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);
```

#### forAddingPlaneShape onDraw()

```
 public void draw(GL10 gl) {


        //color  = colorP;

        // Since this shape uses vertex arrays, enable them
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        // draw the shape

        gl.glColor4f( // set color
                color[0], color[1], color[2], color[3]);

//      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

        gl.glVertexPointer( // point to vertex data:
                COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glDrawElements(
                // draw shape:
                GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                drawListBuffer);




        // Disable vertex array drawing to avoid
        // conflicts with shapes that don't use it
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }
```

### In My Renderer

#### onDrawFrame(gl)

```
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            // Set GL_MODELVIEW transformation mod
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
            //
            gl.glLoadIdentity(); // reset the matrix to its default state

            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_NORMALIZE);
// draw plane
            for (SimplePlane plane : simplePlanes) {
                plane.draw(gl);
            }
```

#### in onSurfaceChanged(gl,height,width)

```
gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        // make adjustments for screen ratio
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); // set matrix to projection mode
        gl.glLoadIdentity(); // reset the matrix to its default state
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 75, ratio, 3, 10000);
        // if (ratio >= 1.0f)
        // gl.glFrustumf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -100.0f); //Landscape
        // else
        // gl.glFrustumf(-1, 1, -1 / ratio, 1 / ratio, 1, 300); //Portrait
        // gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 0.1f, 1000); // apply the
        // projection matrix
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
        // gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);

        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        // gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.glAlphaFunc(GL10.GL_GREATER, 0);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
```

The exact demonstration given in picture.
[image]
 Advanced help would be appreciated !!

Comment: You'll need to provide us with some additional code, particularly the shader code. It's likely your problem lies in the shader.

Comment: If it's GL10 then there isn't any shader code ... but in general more application code would help.

Comment: Thanks @Isogen74 & brohan322 - Please Check edit.  I neither used Shader for GL10 nor any diffusing filter effect and lighting.